# nginx get server port and use it as variable

Tags: nginx

Is there a way to get the server port and use it as var?

To do it like the below example instead of 
`location /file-8081.zip { alias /var/www/8081/file.zip; }` ?

```
server {
    listen       8081;
    server_name  localhost;
    location /file-$server_port.zip { alias /var/www/$server_port/file.zip; }
}
```

I want that each time someone go to `http://ip:$port/file-$port.zip` it will serve the file from the location `/var/www/$port/file.zip`

Comment: The `$server_port` is already a variable. What are you trying to do?

Comment: multiple virtual host, that each virtual host will serve a file `file-$port.zip` from the folder `/var/www/$port/file.zip`

Comment: @RichardSmith with the below example I get `404 Not Found`

Comment: There are two separate questions: 1) rewriting `file-1234.zip` to `.../1234/file.zip`, and 2) checking that `1234` is the same value as the `listen` directive. Is that right?

Comment: @RichardSmith I updated my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this meets your requirements, but I managed to get a working configuration with this:

```
server {
    listen  8080;
    listen  8081;
    listen  8082;
    listen  8083;
    listen  8084;
    listen  8085;
    listen  8086;

    root /var/www;

    rewrite ^(/\w+)-(?<myport>\d+)(\.\w+)$ /$myport$1$3;

    if ($myport != $server_port) {
        return 403;
    }
}
```

Comment: nice, thank you, is there way to create scope of `listen ports` instead of list ? for example 8080-8086 ?

Comment: [The documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) only shows one port per `listen` directive.

Comment: The use of named group (myport) in the regex is nice.